# SQL/CRYSTAL Statement to calculate average datediff()

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have this statement that calculates the difference in time intervals below:

```
(DateDiff ("s",previous({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}) ,{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}))/60
```

Now I want to be able to get that average of that datediff(), this is what I believe should work but I'm getting "The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula". error message:

```
SELECT ({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.USER_ID}), 
       ({USER_MASTER.USER_NAME}),
       Average (diff((DateDiff ("s",previous({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}) ,{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME})))/60
```

Comment: what is the database type ?

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL is the database type

Comment: I keep getting "Remaining text does not appear to be part of formula error when using this SQL provided:SELECT ({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.USER_ID}), 
       ({USER_MASTER.USER_NAME}),
       Average (diff((DateDiff ("s",previous({PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME}) ,{PROD_TRKG_TRAN.MOD_DATE_TIME})))/60

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the data so you can get an average for the group. This can be done in your Query but that will remove the details from the results. If you need to see all the detail lines, then leave the datediff formula and return all the results to your report. Then create groups in your report and create a formula that gets the average for the group(s).